# Finding likeness between one row and many rows

Tags: mysql

Disclaimer: I'm very new to MySQL, doing this as an experiment to learn more.

Essentially, I have a table where one row is the 'master' row. I want to compare this row against a handful of other rows. From that handful, I want to select the one that is the most 'correct' or similar to the master row and store it to a variable. If none of the handful rows are similar enough to the master, I'd just want to cancel the operation.

I can think of a way to do this with iteration, but I keep reading that iteration is very inefficient/bad practice with SQL and want to see if there's another way.

With this example, I'd want to select submission 2, and reject submissions 1 and 3.

```
Type, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3
Master, 100, 200, 300
Submission 1, 100, 400, 300
Submission 2, 100, 200, 300
Submission 3, 200, 100, 300
```

However, in the following example, I'd want to select submission 1, despite the two not being exactly alike.

```
Type, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3
Master, 100, 200, 300
Submission 1, 100, 400, 300
Submission 2 , 100, 500, 500
Submission 3, 200, 100, 300
```

Finally, here I'd want to select Submission 1, as it occurs before Submission 3, despite the two being the same degree of correct.

```
Type, Answer 1, Answer 2, Answer 3
Master, 100, 200, 300
Submission 1, 100, 400, 300
Submission 2 , 100, 500, 500
Submission 3, 500, 200, 300
```

Comment: Can you include a sample table?

Comment: Absolutely - i'll add one now.

Comment: @Drew LOL...your comments are awesome.

Comment: @Drew You have a link?

Comment: It is not at all clear why you would choose the second row?  How are you measuring similarity, and please be precise?

Comment: My apologies, there was a typo. I edited it (again) for clarity.

Comment: What if you had `Submission 4, 100, 100, 300` ?  Which row would you choose?

Comment: In that case, I'd want to select the earlier entry.

Comment: when is a row called 'similar'?

Comment: @PhuDuy, when that row's entries for the Answers 1 2 and 3 columns match that of the Master row.

Comment: Do we need to worry about the possibility of a tie?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the event of a tie, I'd still want to go with the earliest entry.

Comment: i have a little mistake, it has to be 'similar enough to the master'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query.  It computes the number of answers which the `Master` row has in common with each other row.  And in the case of tie by number of right answers, it uses the numerical difference from each wrong answer to choose the closest match.

```
SELECT t.Type, t.Answer1, t.Answer2, t.Answer3,
       (t.a1 + t.a2 + t.a3) AS numRight,
       (t.d1 + t.d2 + t.d3) AS numOff
FROM
(
    SELECT t2.Type, t2.Answer1, t2.Answer2, t2.Answer3,
           CASE WHEN t1.Answer1 = t2.Answer1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS a1,
           CASE WHEN t1.Answer2 = t2.Answer2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS a2,
           CASE WHEN t1.Answer3 = t2.Answer3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS a3,
           ABS(t1.Answer1 - t2.Answer1) ASd1,
           ABS(t1.Answer2 - t2.Answer2) AS d2,
           ABS(t1.Answer3 - t2.Answer3) AS d3
    FROM yourTable t1 INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.Type = 'Master' AND t2.Type <> 'Master'
) t
ORDER BY numRight DESC, numOff
```

If you just want one row, you can add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thank you! This is much more succinct than the solution that I had come up with.